# Thoughts on making a hand-held OCR

Tags: sensor, imageprocessing, image-sensor

I have an electronic project about a OCR that could be held in hand and used like a Tipp-Ex mouse ([image](http://www.normansoffice.co.uk/images/products/zoom/1270550565-16797300.jpg)) to scan words. As I am an amateur in electronics, I don't really know what sensor(s) I can use to get a complete image of the word that I could process afterward. I thought of a gyroscope/accelerometer to track movements and an image sensor.

My questions are about the later:

- What kind of image sensor should I use ? (Resolution, focal point, on chip features,... )
- Is a LED enough to light the text or should I have some laser ?

I think these questions can be (partially) solved using Google but I am more looking for your experience in this field.

Comment: As you are not developing a commercial product, you could buy a variety of cheap ones (e.g. [1](http://www.maplin.co.uk/portable-handheld-scanner-with-ocr-software-390393),[2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Skypix-Cordless-Handheld-Scanner-Resolution/dp/B004DHYGF6/ref=pd_sim_sbs_computers_1)) and take them apart to see how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LED will be more than sufficient for lighting the text. Scanning will be very dependant on getting a good image through optics. If I was doing this I'd consider a "linear" (one-dimensional) CCD as an imaging element; this sort of thing is used in normal 2D flatbed scanners.

As an amateur, minturisation will be your main problem.